# Búsqueda inteligente para trabajar en campos de matriz

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un sistema donde el usuario puede registrar más de un producto de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aqui]

Al hacer clic en el botón, se crea un nuevo campo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aqui]

Cada producto registrado en el pedido, la cantidad se sacrifica de ese pedido. Para que el producto sea derribado correctamente, incluye la siguiente funcionalidade.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aqui]

El problema es que cuando se crea un nuevo campo, no funciona. El código es el siguiente:

```
<table width="100%" >
<tr class="linhas">
<td>
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold" class="bg-light">Produto</td>
<td style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold" class="bg-light">Quantidade</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 40%">
  <input type="text" name="Produto[]" class="form-control buscar" placeholder="Produto" required>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 30%">
  <input type="number" name="Quantidade[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantidade" min="1" required>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
<td style="padding: 5px"><button type="button" class="removerCampo btn btn-danger" title="Remover linha"><i class="fa fa-minus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Remover</button></td>
</tr>              
<tr>
<td colspan="3" class="text-right">
<button type="button" class="adicionarCampo btn btn-success" title="Adicionar Produto"><i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Incluir novo produto</button>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Código que duplica los campos:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
  function removeCampo() {
    $(".removerCampo").unbind("click");
    $(".removerCampo").bind("click", function () {
       if($("tr.linhas").length > 1){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
       }
    });
  }
  $(".adicionarCampo").click(function () {
    novoCampo = $("tr.linhas:first").clone();
    //novoCampo.find("input").val("");
    novoCampo.find('input[type="text"]').val("");
    novoCampo.find('select').val("");
    //novoCampo.find('input[type="radio"]').prop('selected', false);
    novoCampo.insertAfter("tr.linhas:last");
    removeCampo();
  });
});
</script>
```

Código que busca en la base de datos:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".buscar").autocomplete({
            source: '<?php echo $caminhoAbsoluto; ?>/buscar-produtos.php'
        });
    });
</script>
```

**buscar-produtos.php**

```
include("classes/MetodosClass.php");
include("classes/VisualizarClass.php");
$metodos = new MetodosClass();
$buscar = new VisualizarClass();
$produto = $_GET["term"];
echo $buscar->buscarProdutos($produto);
```

**buscarProdutos($produto)**

```
public function buscarProdutos($produto)
{
$produto = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao,$produto);
$sql = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"SELECT * FROM pd_products
                                            WHERE product_name
                                                LIKE '%".$produto."%';");
while($pd = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $buscar[] = $pd["product_name"];
}
return json_encode($buscar);
}
```

¿Cómo hago que la lista de productos funcione en los otros campos que creo?

Answer (score 0):

Inténtalo de este modo, primero poniéndole nombre a la función que te hace el autocomplete y ejecutándola durante la carga incial, de este modo:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
      function recargarBuscar() {
        $(".buscar").autocomplete({
            source: '<?php echo $caminhoAbsoluto; ?>/buscar-produtos.php'
        });
      }
      recargarBuscar();
    });
</script>
```

y después la invocas al final del evento click sobre la clase `.adicionarCampo`, justo después de agregar un nuevo elemento:

```
novoCampo.insertAfter("tr.linhas:last");
recargarBuscar();
removeCampo();
```

de este modo localizará todos los elementos con la clase `.buscar` que haya actualmente en el DOM y les asignará el `autocomplete` si no lo tenian aún asignado.